# how to get the current working directory in rcptt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am trying to get the current working directory using rcptt. I am trying the below command:

```
proc "get-env" [val name] {
    invoke-static "org.eclipse.rcptt.util" "java.lang.System" getProperty $name
}
```

then call this proc like

```
get-env "user.dir"
```

But it returns actually my AUT directory, not the current location.

I have written some test cases in rcptt ide, i want to get the location of those test cases.

How i can get the current working location using rcptt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RCPTT does not provide information on the "AUT-runner" or the current Test Case being executed.
You need to extend RCPTT to get such information.